# Which wallets have support for BIP 70 - 72 for merchant message transactions?

Tags: merchants, transaction-messaging

Which wallets support merchant message transactions such as bip 70 - 72? I want to build static html page where a user can just send their btc to my address with a message attached to it. The message would just be their email address so I can send them an order confirmation.

From my understanding the URI: "bitcoin:1zsfkje2034908234" would just have the *r* parameter and you would just specify a url for the wallet to goto. This url would just be something like this I'd assume: http://www.example.com?phone=83282829323

Let me know if this is even possible or if this is even correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been searching for the same and found [this article](https://bitpay.com/docs/wallets). Below I put the wallets that support **Bitcoin URIs** (BIP 21) and **Payment Protocol** (BIPs 70, 71, 72,73). For more info please check the link.

```
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
|            Wallet             | Bitcoin URIs | Payment Protocol |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
| Bitcoin Core (Satoshi client) | V            | V                |
| BitPay Wallet                 | V            | V                |
| Breadwallet                   | V            | V                |
| Mycelium                      | V            | V                |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

And add Copay to the table, which also supports BIPs 70-73 and is not in the link. For your URI question check [this answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-implement-a-payment-processor-using-bitcoin-without-using-a-3rd-party-to-do-most-of-the-work).

That's all I can do for you. Hope it helps!